# Twisted - Pass Protocol (and socket handle) object to Twisted subprocess

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, twisted

Using the following code it seems I can fairly easily reconstruct a socket in a child process using multiprocessing.reduction..

```
import socket,os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.reduction import reduce_handle, rebuild_handle

client = socket.socket()
client.connect(('google.com', 80))

rd = reduce_handle(client.fileno())

print "Parent: %s" % (os.getpid())

def test(x):
        print "Child: %s" % (os.getpid())

        build = rebuild_handle(x)
        rc = socket.fromfd(build, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        rc.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n')
        print rc.recv(1024)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(rd,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

I have a Twisted game server that runs multiple matches at the same time. These matches may contain several players, each of whom has a Protocol instance. What I'd like to do is have matches split across a pool of Twisted subprocesses, and have the pools handle the clients of the matches they're processing themselves. It seems like reading/writing the client's data and passing that data to and from the subprocesses would be unnecessary overhead.

The Protocols are guaranteed to be TCP instances so I believe I can (like the above code) reduce the socket like this:

```
rd = reduce_handle(myclient.transport.fileno())
```

Upon passing that data to a subprocess by looking at the Twisted source it seems I can reconstruct it in a subprocess now like this:

```
import socket
from twisted.internet import reactor, tcp
from multiprocessing.reduction import reduce_handle, rebuild_handle

handle = rebuild_handle(rd)
sock = socket.fromfd(handle, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
protocol = MyProtocol(...)
transport = tcp.Connection(sock, protocol, reactor=reactor)
protocol.transport = transport
```

I would just try this, but seeing as I'm not super familiar with the Twisted internals even if this works I don't really know what the implications might be.

Can anyone tell me whether this looks right and whether it would work? Is this inadvisable for any some reason (I've never seen it mentioned in Twisted documentation or posts even though it seems quite relevant)? If this works, anything I should be wary of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted and the multiprocessing module are incompatible with each other.  If the code appears to work, it's only by luck and accident and a future version of either (there may well be no future versions of multiprocessing but there will probably be futures versions of Twisted) might turn this good luck into bad luck.

`twisted.internet.tcp` also isn't a great module to use in your applications.  It's not exactly private but you also can't rely on it always working with the reactor your application uses, either.  For example, iocp reactor uses `twisted.internet.iocpreactor.tcp` instead and will not work at all with `twisted.internet.tcp` (I don't expect it's very likely you'll be using iocp reactor with this code and the rest of the reactors Twisted ships with do use `twisted.internet.tcp` but third-party reactors may not and future versions of Twisted may change how the reactors are implemented).

There are two parts of the problem you're solving.  One part is conveying the file descriptor between two processes.  The other part is convincing the reactor to start monitoring the file descriptor and dispatching its events.

It's possible the risk of using `multiprocessing.reduction` with Twisted is minimal because there doesn't seem to be anything to do with process management in that module.  Instead, it's just about pickling sockets.  So you may be able to continue to convey your file descriptors using that method (and you might want to do this if you wanted to avoid using Twisted in the parent process for some reason - I'm not sure, but it doesn't sound like this is the case).  However, an alternative to this is to use `twisted.python.sendmsg` to pass these descriptors over a UNIX socket - or better yet, to use a higher-level layer that handles the fiddly `sendmsg` bits for you: `twisted.protocols.amp`.  AMP supports an argument type that is a file descriptor, letting you pass file descriptors between processes (again, only over a UNIX socket) just like you'd pass any other Python object.

As for the second part, you can add an already-established TCP connection to the reactor using `reactor.adoptStreamConnection`.  This is a public interface that you can rely on (as long as the reactor actually implements it - which not all reactors do: you can introspect the reactor using `twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorSocket.providedBy(reactor)` if you want to do some kind of graceful degradation or user-friendly error reporting).

Comment: `multiprocessing.reduction` seems to be cross platform (Windows and unix) as long as you're able to get to the raw socket in Twisted, whereas sendmsg seems to be unix specific. That's one immediate drawback, however, I'm not working on Windows anyway. Aside from that, this all makes sense. Thank you!